# Terraform gcp get internal private ip of instance and write to file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Working on the following example [github](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-docs-samples/blob/main/flask_google_cloud_quickstart/main.tf) i am trying to add a static internal ip value  to terraform ( so instance will run with specific internal ip ) or at least get the internal ip of the instance so i can write it in the internal file of the instance.

Any suggestion or thoughts on this one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check how terraform works with [an IP address resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_address)

A particulare example (from the top of my head, assuming that the subnetwork (`my_subnet`) is created in the same terraform batch):

```
resource "google_compute_address" "my_internal_ip_addr" {
  project      = "my_target_project_id"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  region       = "my_region"
  subnetwork   = data.google_compute_subnetwork.my_subnet.name
  name         = "my_ip_address_name"
  description  = "An internal IP address for my VM"
}
```

and for a compute engine (ony relevant elements):

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "my_vm" {
  project      = "my_target_project_id"
  name         = "my_vm"

  # other items omitted

  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = data.google_compute_subnetwork.my_subnet.name
    subnetwork_project = "my_target_project_id"
    network_ip         = google_compute_address.my_internal_ip_addr.address

    access_config {
      # Include this section to give the VM an external IP address
    }
  }

  # other items omitted
}
```

However, I don't know if the above can help you with your ultimate requirement to `i can write it in the internal file of the instance` and why you need that.

Comment: Thank you sir,
Worked as needed, the idea to write the the static ip to internal file is to create a dynamic cluster for a specific app. So the internal ip is to be specified in a local file instance the created machine. This can be created via script i guess but to keep things inside terraform would be perfect.

Comment: I would think about a `metadata` data element of the `google_compute_instance` resource. I think it is possble to provide quite a lot of things there, including values defined within terraform scripts. - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#metadata